# JUEL mathematics

Tags: java, juel

I'm programming server on java, and I need to use math with the help of JUEL.

For example 2*2+2 and it will print out the result 6. 
The problem is, it doesn't work.

Here is a method for mathematics:

```
public static void Math(String operation){

    ValueExpression expr = f.createValueExpression(cont, "${" + operation + "}", Object.class);
    out.print(expr);

}
```

So, I take an operation as String "8+5+4"and print out result on conlsole.

May be I use JUEL in a wrong way?

```
try{
        while ((newLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
               Pattern patternMath = Pattern.compile("<MATH>(\\s*?)(\\d+)(\\s*?)([-+/\\*])(\\s*?)(\\d+)");
               Matcher matcher = patternMath.matcher(newLine);

                Pattern pattCSEN = Pattern.compile("<RU-EN>(.*)");
                Matcher matCSEN = pattCSEN.matcher(newLine);

                Pattern pattENCS = Pattern.compile("<EN-RU>(.*)");
                Matcher matENCS = pattENCS.matcher(newLine);




                if (matENCS.find()) {out.println("<TRANSLATION> " + ENGtoCZ(matENCS.group(1)));}
                else if (matCSEN.find()) {out.println("<TRANSLATION> " + CZtoENG(matCSEN.group(1)));}
               else if (newLine.equals("<BYE>")) {
                    clientSocket.close();

                }
                else  if (matcher.find()) {

               Math(newLine);

                } else {
                    out.println("<FAIL>");
                    clientSocket.close();

                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                clientSocket.close();;
            }}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println("<FAIL>");
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: 'it does not work' is a fairly poor problem description - what exactly does not work?

Comment: After getting in this metod, the socket closes.

Comment: A socket is not even visible in the code you have posted. Please show more code...

Comment: It still do not understand it - does the expression evaluation itself work or do you have a socket communication issue? Try to create some unit tests. Does `out` relate to `clientSocket` in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the following lines to always make sure that you have in your code.
Make sure you have the context set up something like the following:

```
SimpleContext context = new SimpleContext();
```

You expression object should be of the Implemented class, something like the following:

```
ExpressionFactory factory = new ExpressionFactoryImpl();
```

> [JUEL Api](http://juel.sourceforge.net/juel.pdf)

Secondly put your ValueExpression in a try block, in case anything goes wrong, you will know the problem from the caught exception.

Check how expression is entered with a `System.out` as in:

```
Object display = expr.getValue(context);
System.out.println("> " + display);
```

> Some additional reference is [Here](http://juel.sourceforge.net/guide/basic/value.html#tree)